# \answerline label not syncing with \bonustitledquestion name

Tags: exam

I was writing an exam with a bonus question at the end.  Instead of having a number, I wanted it to say bonus as the question title and then have an answer line that says the same thing.  As an example I have:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10] Normal question
\answerline
\bonustitledquestion{Bonus:}[1] Bonus question
\answerline
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The first answer line is numbered as 1, but the second answer line is numbered as 2 instead of saying bonus.  Is there anyway to change this?